# Asking for a raise - By looking for an alternative

Tags: salary

I have asked my manager for a discussion about salary 4 weeks ago.
I have had no answer, with the manager avoiding the topic.

I have the belief that the only real leverage in that type of bargain to is have alternative job offer on the table.
I enjoy my current job, but i got recently approached by a headhunter and decided to go through the process and see where it leads.

I am not that interested in the other job, rather in the negociating position that it would put me at my current one.

Im now contemplating the following question, do I really need that alternative offer to bring it to my manager?

I could just say I have another offer and attempt to negociate (while it not being the case).

Maybe it is worth mentioning that i have good relationship, with my manager, and that I managed a project that is quite tricky (construction project) and that it would certainly be a hassle at best for them to replace me if I were to leave.

What could be the pitfall of that approach?

Comment: This is the answer I gave to someone in a similar-ish position: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/188902/how-to-negotiate-a-raise-if-they-want-me-to-get-an-offer-letter/188909#188909 - if you get to the point you have an offer, take that and don't bother with your old employer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an external offer in salary negotiation WITHOUT threatening to quit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98790/how-to-use-an-external-offer-in-salary-negotiation-without-threatening-to-quit)

Comment: You have a good relationship with your manager, and you want to lie to them?

Comment: “I have a good relationship with my manager”. “He avoids discussing my salary”. News flash : you **don’t** have a good relationship.

Comment: When was the last time you got a raise?

Does your company not have a biyearly review/ salary adjustment? (If the answer was no) And you think that they are a good company to work for?

Answer (score 2):

No, your idea is not the right approach if you really want to stay.  As noted in another answer, if you come in with a competitive job offer many companies will simply show you the door.  But even if they don't, extracting pay raises under such circumstances are almost always counter-productive in the long run if you decide to stay.  You gain a short-term increase at the expense of longer-term opportunities and increases.

I suggest that your best approach is twofold:

1. Research the current and local market and find out what people with similar skills and experience are being paid.  You should be able to come up with a compensation range.  Assess where you fall into that range.  The lower you rank the better for you in the process.
2. Carefully document what your contributions are worth to the company.  This can be difficult and time-consuming but it's the most important part of this process. Detail problems you have solved, clients you have  brought in or retained, whatever it is you have done and put a price tag on it.  Also figure out what it would cost the company, both in direct hiring costs, training and so on to replace you but also lost opportunity by having a less experienced person filling your spot.

Using that information put together a 1 or 2 page presentation that you can pitch in 5 minutes or less.  (Similar to the "elevator pitch" they teach you in sales training.)  But have backup documentation ready and with you so that you can pull it out and defend anything in your presentation.

Now you are prepared for a salary discussion.  Press the issue with your manager.  If you have to, camp out at their office until you get a meeting.  Many manager dislike such discussions because they get tired of the usual "I deserve a raise because stuff is so expensive now..."  That's NOT the company's problems, it's yours.  Your presentation will be a refreshing change from the usual salary conversation and, if you are well prepared, things should go well.

If not, well you now have some fantastic material for an interview with another company.  But leave that until later if its needed.

Never "threaten" your manager with "give me a raise or I'll leave".  You want to have a very positive meeting and leave them feeling really good about you, your work, your attitude, and your future with the company.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the pitfall of that approach?

Really?

"OK, thanks for your time here Jim. We'll start the process with HR to finish your employment in two weeks."

Oh dear, you're unemployed.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a stretch to assume the OP is from a country with no labor laws to speak of.

Comment: I agree it's a stretch. But walking in to your boss's office and saying "I've got a job offer elsewhere" certainly could result in a poisoning of the allegedly good relationship the OP has with their manager.

Comment: Particularly if it isn't a real offer. The boss may not take it as an explicit resignation, but he can still call the bluff with "we think you're worth what you're paid, you're free to go if that isn't enough, and by the way, we're now going to work on the assumption you will be leaving soon anyway".